# Compare 2 characters and Assign to a New Column

Tags: r

I have a list of data which looks like:

```
ID    col1    col1.1    col2    col2.1    col3    col3.1
rat    AG       AB       AG       AC       AA       AA
cat    BB       GG       BB       CC       AB       AG
dog    --       AB       AG       GG       CC       GG
```

I want to compare between each of the two columns (ie col1 vs col1.1, col2 vs col2.1 ...) and if they meet a condition, it will add the result to a new column.

So lets say the condition is like this:

```
if any base of one column matched with -- of another column, assign 0
if AG or AC of one column matched with AB of another column, assign 1
if AA of one column matched with AA of another column, assign 2
if BB of one column matched with GG or CC of another column, assign 3
if one does not match any of the condition above, assign 4
```

So that the output looks like:

```
ID    col1    col1.1  OUT1  col2    col2.1  OUT2  col3  col3.1   OUT3  
rat    AG       AB     1     AG       AC     1     AA     AA      2
cat    BB       GG     3     BB       CC     3     AB     AG      1
dog    --       AB     0     AG       GG     4     BB     GG      3
```

How can I do the comparison between the two strings and add a new column to it?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Take a look at `ifelse`.

Answer (score 2):

This should let you get what you need with a bit of rearrangement:

```
fnpair <- function(a) { if( a[1] =="--" | a[2]=="--"){0}else{
                  if( (a[1] %in% c("AG", "AC") & a[2] == "AB")|
                      (a[2] %in% c("AG", "AC") & a[1] == "AB") ){1}else{
                     if(  a[1] =="AA" & a[2] == "AA" ){2} else{
                        if(  (a[1] %in% c("GG","CC") & a[2] == "BB")|
                             (a[2] %in% c("GG","CC") & a[1] == "BB") ) {3} else{4} }}}}

 df1 <- read.table(text="ID    col1    col1.1    col2    col2.1    col3    col3.1
 rat    AG       AB       AG       AC       AA       AA
 cat    BB       GG       BB       CC       AB       AG
 dog    --       AB       AG       GG       CC       GG", header=TRUE)

 t( apply(df1[,2:7], 1, function(x) t( sapply(0:2, function(z) fnpair(x[2*z+c(1,2)]) ) ) ) )

#------------------

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    2
[2,]    3    3    1
[3,]    0    4    4
```

To assign to a new column just:

```
df1$newcol <- .Last.value
```

I think the hand calculations you show do not adhere to the rules.

Comment: Thanks! But how do you figure out the equation for fnpair(x[2*z+c(1,2)])?

Comment: It's just application of standard logic. I went through your specifications one by one and built expressions that represented the rules.